# Setting a resolution for xvfb-run and wkhtmltopdf / wkhtmltoimage

Tags: centos, wkhtmltopdf, xvfb, wkhtmltoimage

I'm trying desperately to give xvfb-run some resolution arguments to take screenshots of websites with wkhtmltox in different resolutions.

I'm using both xvfb-run and wkhtmltox on CentOS.

```
xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0 1024x768x24" wkhtmltoimage http://www.whatismyscreenresolution.com/ /tmp/bla.png
```

Unfortunately my arguments are not respected by xvfb-run. It has always a resolution of 800x600. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 7):

You forgot this option: `--use-xserver`.

So the whole command is:

```
xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0 1024x768x24" wkhtmltoimage --use-xserver http://www.whatismyscreenresolution.com/ /tmp/bla.png
```

(I tested with wkhtmltopdf, but it should be the same with wkhtmltoimage)

Comment: @kip: It would be helpful if you wrote how exactly it doesn't work for you. Judging by upvotes (and lack of other comments) this solution should work, and it definitely worked for me at the time.

Comment: For future googlers, I tried this and got `Xvfb failed to start` and I found I needed to include `:1` in the server-args: `--server-args=":1 -screen 0 1024x768x24"`

Answer (score 2):

Add a comma between parameters. In your case `"-screen 0, 1024x768x24"`.
Let me know if it helped you.
Regards,
HBK

Answer (score 1):

Are you running wkhtmltoimage with a patched QT? If your QT version is NOT patched, a lot of features are ignored, including any commands sent from xvfb-run.

you can check your version like so:

```
/usr/bin/wkhtmltoimage --version
```

Change the path to wherever you've stored your `wkhtmltoimage` file. If the returned version doesn't include "patched QT", then that's probably where you should start. You can download a patched QT version from here:

```
https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html
```

Installation of a patched QT version is not *too* complicated, try a variation of the following (I'm running Ubuntu 20, other distros will need tweaking):

```
cd ~
wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/0.12.6-1/wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.focal_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.focal_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage --version
```

Best of luck.